# java threads appear not to be released

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to implement a really simple echo-back multi-threaded server.
I used the thread pool created with [`newFixedThreadPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-), but it looks like the number of concurrent connections is fixed at `nThreads` (passed into `newFixedThreadPool`). For example, if I set `nThreads` to 3, then the fourth client that connects cannot interact with the server.

This is rather weird because the documentation says "*Creates a thread pool that **reuses** a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue.*"
Since the documentation also says that "*If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a thread is available.*" I suspect my threads are never "released" so that they never became available for reuse.

I think this could be a silly mistake, but I couldn't figure out what's wrong. Here's my client handler's `run()` method, which I think is very similar to the code found [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/SocketProgramming/SocketProgram.html) (`client` below is just a `Socket` connected to the client):

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()))) {

        String input;
        while(true) {
            input = readLine();
            if(input == null)
                break;

            out.write(input);
            out.newLine();
            out.flush();
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e, "Error from socket IO.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    try {
        client.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e, "Error when closing socket.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("Client " + client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() +
                        " closed connection.\n");
}
```

EDIT 1: I guess I should clarify that clients will immediately disconnect after receiving the response. So the threads should become available very soon.

EDIT 2: Here's the code that handles connection (`listen` is a `ServerSocket`):

```
while(true) {
    Socket client = null;
    try {
        client = listen.accept();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e, "Error when waiting for connection.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("New connection from client: " +
            client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + "\n"
    );

    threadPool.execute(new ConnectionHandler(client));
}
```

This is the thread pool initialization (in the constructor): `this.threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();`.

EDIT 3: Log messages (when `nThread = 3`, so the fourth connection is never really handled):

```
New connection from client: 127.0.0.1

Client 127.0.0.1 closed connection.

New connection from client: 127.0.0.1

Client 127.0.0.1 closed connection.

New connection from client: 127.0.0.1

Client 127.0.0.1 closed connection.

New connection from client: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: When your code exists the `run` method, the `Thread` is returned to the pool

Comment: when the 4th client has connected have any of the first 3 disconnected? ie. do you see your "closed connection" message?

Comment: The behavior you described is according to the documentation you quoted. Why is it weird?

Comment: Note: you probably don't want System.exit(1); if there is an exception. an error on one connection should not bring down the whole server

Comment: add some diagnostic output to your code to see if while loop ever exists

Comment: @slipperyseal Yes I saw the "closed connection" message for each of the client. Basically my clients don't reuse connections, so they close connections immediately after receiving responses. As for `System.exit(1)`, yes that can be improved.

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev I can see the "closed connection" messages, so I think `while` loop does exit.

Comment: @Oleg Well if threads will be "reused", shouldn't my server be able to handle more connections if previous clients disconnect?

Comment: perhaps you need to add the code which does the connection / thread handling

Comment: You should add an indicator of `run` method starting. You could be blocking on `input = readline()`

Comment: maybe also check it's not an issue with your client code as well. if it uses a similar thread pool etc :)

Comment: @matt I don't think so because I can see the "...closed connection" message which is printed at the end of `run`.

Comment: @slipperyseal The client does not use a thread pool. I've tried with clients written in Java & Python, same issue, so I think it's with the server. I mean I can make it work using `newCachedThreadPool`, but I want to know what I did wrong with `newFixedThreadPool` : )

Comment: @user8680580, that's very interesting. So, it basically works with cached thread pool but not with a fixed one, right?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. Post a complete server code, and a complete client code.

Comment: You claim your fourth client the run method is not starting. I am asking you to check if your run method is starting the fourth time, and that it isn't actually blocking on readline. Then you claim it is starting. What is it? Are you sure the run method is starting and you are not blocking on `input = readline()` for the fourth connection.

Comment: I'd also log Thread IDs, so you know which connection has been handled on which thread. And if they are actually reused.

Comment: @Vasiliy Yes, and I think that's understandable because `newCachedThreadPool` will just keep creating new threads if needed while `newFixedThreadPool` will not. And that's why I suspected the threads are not released.

Comment: @matt Sorry man. But you didn't say "fourth" before. No I don't think for the fourth client `run` started, but I'll have to verify that with some extra log.

Comment: Two more thing you might check, first you 'handle' an IOException, but if a different Exception gets thrown then you'll exit the run method without any notification. The second one, fire up a profiler so you can see the state of the threads.

Comment: @matt In the case of a swallowed exception a new Thread would take the failed one's place, though.

Comment: @user8680580 Have you tried a 5th client? Regardless of whether #4 "hangs" or not?

Comment: @Fildor who says it doesn't? From the evidence provided, the only reason to think the fourth connection doesn't work is because there is never a 'closed connection' statement logged.

Comment: @matt "Edit 3" clearly shows they *are* logged.

Comment: @Fildor exactly, edit three shows two log statements per connection, open and closed. The fourth thread never logs a closed statement.

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions. If you are asked for additional information, [edit] it into the question. People who want to suggest a solution should *post an answer*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an answer to why the forth connection is hanging, other than to say here is a version of the code which does work...

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket listen = new ServerSocket(9999);
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        while(true) {
            Socket client = null;
            try {
                client = listen.accept();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
            System.out.println("New connection from client: " +
                    client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + "\n"
            );

            threadPool.execute(new ConnectionHandler(client));
        }
    }
}

class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
    private Socket client;

    public ConnectionHandler(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()))) {

            String input;
            while(true) {
                input = in.readLine();
                if(input == null)
                    break;

                out.write(input);
                out.newLine();
                out.flush();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error from socket IO.");
        }

        try {
            client.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error when closing socket.");
        }
        System.out.println("Client " + client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() +
                " closed connection.\n");
    }
}
```

I connected with telnet, echoed some characters and disconnected. I did this 5 times.

```
    New connection from client: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1

    Client 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 closed connection.

    New connection from client: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1

    Client 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 closed connection.

    New connection from client: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1

    Client 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 closed connection.

    New connection from client: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1

    Client 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 closed connection.

    New connection from client: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1

    Client 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 closed connection.
```

The only difference is the code in the question has the line...

```
input = readLine();
```

where as I needed to change it to

```
input = in.readLine();
```

to be valid. I'm wondering if in the code which hasn't been posted to the question contains a static variable or some other kind of shenanigans.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried to reproduce my problem, and I found out the issue (and it's indeed very silly).

On my server side I want to be able to shut down the server when "exit" is entered in the console, so I created a `InputHandler` class (which implements `Runnable`) to handle server side input. It looks like this:

```
class InputHandler implements Runnable {
    private Server server;

    InputHandler(Server server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String input = System.console().readLine();
        if(input.toLowerCase().equals("exit"))
            server.shutdown();
        else
            System.err.println("Invalid command. To exit enter \"exit\".");
    }
}
```

and my server's `run()` actually looks like this:

```
private void loop() {
    while(true) {
        threadPool.execute(new InputHandler(this));

        Socket client = null;
        try {
            client = listen.accept();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error when waiting for connection.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("New connection from client: " +
            client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + "\n"
        );

        threadPool.execute(new Handler(client));
    }
}
```

Basically a new `InputHandler` thread is created in each iteration...(`threadPool.execute(new InputHandler(this));`). Moving this code up one line will fix it...

I didn't mention `InputHandler` before because it appeared to be irrelevant to me. Sadly in the end it turned out to be it.

**I'm very sorry I wasted you guys' time. My apologies. Feel free to downvote if you wish : )** For now I will accept *slipperyseal*'s answer. Thank you again for all the help.

Comment: don't apologise. solving problems like this is the life of the programmer. you sometimes have to think outside the box and you find the issue isn't where you thought it was - eg. when i suggested checking the client code. but i did warn you about those System.exit() calls :) in regular app development you shouldn't use them at all, or in very limited places :)

Comment: @slipperyseal Thx for the comments! Would you say simply `return` from `run()` is good enough to replace `System.exit()`?

Comment: when you return from the public static void main() method, the program normally terminates (normally). when you have multiple threads involved, you should only call system exit when you specifically want to kill the whole program from there. sometimes you might want to call System.exit() at the end of your main method if you know there are daemon threads from libraries (eg. a database connection pool), or your own ConnectionHandler threads, which will keep the program running.

Comment: Yes, quite silly. Making mistakes is fine, happens to all of us, what's important is to learn from them. Looking at your second question you didn't learn anything. Please post your actual code next time, don't remove something that appears irrelevant and don't post things from memory. Creating an MCVE is great but you must verify that your problem still exists after you created it. This question could've been answered in 20 seconds and your makefile from the other question might have something relevant that changes the answer. I do appreciate you owning it, and posting this answer so +1.